# Read next line during file IO in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I am trying to import a file using ruby and parse it. Is there a way to read the next line once inside the file import? Basically I want to see if a specific line is within x lines of another important line. Like does "x phrase" Come within 10 lines of "y phrase". I don't see a way to do this -- I know its simple with Java. 
Thanks!

Comment: _"I know its simple with Java"_ – could you provide a Java example?

Comment: What do you mean "once inside the file import"?

Comment: Hi, so basically what I have is File.open(web_contents).each do |line| and inside there I want to have something like a while loop that checks the lines after line. So the following lines. And in java .nextLine() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595368/reading-the-next-line-in-a-text-file. So I'm trying to figure out a ruby alternative. Thank you

Comment: If you need finer control, call `File.open(web_contents) do |file|` (without `each`) and within that block call `file.readline` to get the next line as often as you want.

Comment: Import your file as an array, and then use an array slice to search by maximum "distance."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read lines of a file

```
lines_array = IO.readlines('testfile')
lines_array.each { |l| #Do your stuff with your line }
```

Voilà

[Ruby Docs on IO](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-readlines)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
web_contents = "c:\\path\\to\\your\\file.txt"  

File.open(web_contents).each_with_index do |line, i|  
  line.chomp!  
  puts "line #{line}, i #{i}" # Do whatever you want to here  
end
```

The `.each_with_index` method gives you an index, `i`, which you can use to keep track of where on what line in your file you are. Simple maths can then yield the offset as required.